# Need help to limit months (MM) to 01-12 in Regex Expiration Date (MM/YY) client-side validation JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a form which a user will enter the Credit Card Expiration Date in the field. I have this JavaScript code for client-side validation to limit the input to numbers only, AND also the slash "/" automatically appears once the 3rd number (**Y**Y) is typed.

I need help with updating the code to accept only 01-12 for the first two digits (MM). Currently it accepts any number for months.

Here is the code:
`onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,''); if (this.value.length > 5) { this.value=this.value.substr(0,5); }"`

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you're doing this validation with code already, why not just check if the number is `>= 1` and `<= 12`?

Comment: Use dropdowns for month and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `/^(1[0-2]|0[0-9])(\d)$/g` as `regex` and I added two validation for `00` month and second to ensure only allow user to input year data when regex passes.

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(1[0-2]|0[0-9])(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,''); if (this.value.length > 5) { this.value=this.value.substr(0,5); } if (this.value.indexOf('/') < 0 && this.value.length>2 || this.value=='00') { this.value=this.value.substr(0,1); }">
```

Comment: yes it helped! What if I want to limit the number of decimals/periods to only one input by the user for a similar "Amount/Dollar field" function? **onkeyup="if (!RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d*$/).test(this.value)) { this.value = this.value.replace(RegExp(/[A-Za-z-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:;'<>?,\/]+/).exec(this.value), '').replace(String.fromCharCode(34), '');}"**